# Execute command stored in aux file

Tags: auxiliary-files

My script needs to read a command from one aux file (testFileWriteReadExecute.yposIN.txt), then execute that same command which is a actually a call to a write macro which writes another command to a second file (testFileWriteReadExecute.yposOUT.txt).

Currently it produces the command in the PDF output instead of executing it. At some stage I had something similar working halfway, but have messed it up since, unfortunately.

testFileWriteReadExecute.yposin.txt looks like this:

```
\writeVerse{A}{1}{F}\comment{30580738}\endcomment
\writeVerse{A}{1}{L}\comment{29138946}\endcomment
\writeVerse{A}{2}{F}\comment{29138946}\endcomment
\writeVerse{A}{2}{L}\comment{27566082}\endcomment
\writeVerse{A}{3}{F}\comment{27566082}\endcomment
\writeVerse{A}{3}{L}\comment{25993218}\endcomment
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, fontsize=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=11.2cm, paperheight=17.4cm, top=1cm,bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \newwrite\yposoutputfile%
    \openout\yposoutputfile=\jobname.yposout.txt%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
    \closeout\yposoutputfile%
}

\newcommand\writeVerse[3][]{%
  \writelines{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

% Write the position to file.
\def\writelines#1#2#3{%
  \pdfsavepos%
    \write\yposoutputfile{%
    \string\writeVerse%
    \string{#1\string}%
    \string{#2\string}%
        \string{#3\string}%
        \string\comment\string{\the\pdflastypos\string}\string\endcomment%
    }%
}

% Open the file to read the commands.
\def\fromFile{
  \newread\yposinputfile%
  \openin\yposinputfile=\jobname.yposin.txt%
    \readline\yposinputfile to \fromFileLine%
  \closein\yposinputfile%
  \fromFileLine
}

\begin{document}
\fromFile %\writeVerse{A}{1}{F}
 LIBRO de la generación de Jesucristo, hijo de David, hijo de Abraham. \fromFile %\writeVerse{A}{1}{L}
\writeVerse{A}{2}{F} \textbf{2}~Abraham engendró á Isaac: é Isaac engendró á Jacob: y Jacob engendró á Judas y á sus hermanos:\writeVerse{A}{2}{L}
\writeVerse{A}{3}{F} \textbf{3}~Y Judas engendró de Thamar á Phares y á Zara: y Phares engendró á Esrom: y Esrom engendró á Aram:\writeVerse{A}{3}{L}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

The basic concept of what I want is simple.

1. The `XeLaTeX` script grabs a line from the one text file which
   happens to be a `TeX` command, i.e. `\writeVerse{A}{1}{F}`
2. It places in a particular place of the document this command, where this
   command gets executed/expanded instead of printed.
3. The command is a call to a macro which in turn writes to another file.

## EDIT 2:

Since the closest answer is this one by egreg I'll accept it, although it does not answer the fundamentals of my question. It does seem that this is a limitation in TeX.

Comment: Your `\fromFile` command always reads the first line, because it opens and closes the file each time. But the main problem is that it can't be read, because it has been also opened for writing in it, so it's empty when `\fromFile` is found.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, but I thought I circumvented that issue by using two files. A `\jobname.yposIN.txt` and a `\jobname.yposOUT.txt`. Did I miss something there?

Comment: You want to read an inexistent file.

Comment: @egreg Did you mean the input file? I've created the input file by some other means (manually in this case), that's why I've given the contents thereof separately. The output file gets created by the `tex` script. Both exists with contents after the `xelatex` run, although the output is shorting the first two lines, due to the write command not executing.

Comment: Have a look at `\th@mbs@verview` from  the [thumbs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumbs) package: "The internal command `\th@mbs@verview` reads a line from file `\jobname.tmb` and executes the content of that line - if that line has not been processed yet, in which case it is just ignored (see `\@unused`)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand what `\fromFile` should do. However, you can avoid juggling the files by doing the write in the standard `.aux` file, and then overwriting the old "ypos" file at begin document.

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, fontsize=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=11.2cm,
  paperheight=17.4cm,
  top=1cm,bottom=1cm,
  left=1cm,
  right=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fontspec}

% Allocate an output and an input stream
\newwrite\yposfileout
\newread\yposfilein

% If the file has been written, open it for reading
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \immediate\closeout\yposfileout
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.ypos.txt}
    {\openin\yposfilein=\jobname.ypos.txt}
    {\let\fromFile\relax}
}

% Write the position to file.
\makeatletter
\def\writelines#1#2#3{%
  \pdfsavepos%
  \write\@auxout{%
    \string\rewriteVerse{%
      \string\writeVerse{#1}{#2}{#3}%
      \string\comment\string{\the\pdflastypos\string}\string\endcomment
    }}%
}
\newif\if@writeverseopened
% when the `.aux` file is being read in at begin document, write out a new ypos file
\def\rewriteVerse#1{%
  \if@writeverseopened\else
    \immediate\openout\yposfileout=\jobname.ypos.txt
    \@writeverseopenedtrue
  \fi
  \immediate\write\yposfileout{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}
% Do nothing when the aux file is read in at end document
\AtEndDocument{\let\rewriteVerse\@gobble}

% Read the commands from the ypos file
\def\fromFile{%
  \readline\yposfilein to \fromFileLine
  \texttt{\fromFileLine}
}
\makeatother

% \writeVerse has an optional argument and two mandatory ones
\newcommand\writeVerse[3][]{%
  \writelines{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}


\begin{document}
\fromFile \writeVerse[A]{1}{F} LIBRO de la generación de Jesucristo,
hijo de David, hijo de Abraham. \fromFile \writeVerse[A]{1}{L}
\writeVerse[A]{2}{F} \textbf{2}~Abraham engendró á Isaac: é Isaac
engendró á Jacob: y Jacob engendró á Judas y á sus
hermanos:\writeVerse[A]{2}{L} \writeVerse[A]{3}{F} \textbf{3}~Y Judas
engendró de Thamar á Phares y á Zara: y Phares engendró á Esrom: y
Esrom engendró á Aram:\writeVerse[A]{3}{L}
\end{document}
```

---

You can use two files, provided your script changes the name of the former output file to the input file.

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, fontsize=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=11.2cm,
  paperheight=17.4cm,
  top=1cm,bottom=1cm,
  left=1cm,
  right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{atveryend,pdftexcmds}

\newwrite\yposfileout
\newread\yposfilein
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.yposin.txt}
    {\openin\yposfilein=\jobname.yposin.txt}
    {\let\fromFile\relax}
  \immediate\openout\yposfileout=\jobname.yposout.txt
}

% Write the position to file.
\def\writelines#1#2#3{%
  \pdfsavepos%
  \write\yposfileout{%
    \string\writeVerse{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \string\comment\string{\the\pdflastypos\string}\string\endcomment
    }%
}
% Open the file to read the commands.
\def\fromFile{%
  \readline\yposfilein to \fromFileLine
  \texttt{\fromFileLine}
}

\makeatletter
\AtVeryEndDocument{%
  \closein\yposfilein
  \immediate\closeout\yposfileout
  \ifnum\pdf@shellescape>\z@
    \immediate\write18{mv \jobname.yposout.txt \jobname.yposin.txt}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\writeVerse[3][]{%
  \writelines{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}


\begin{document}
\fromFile \writeVerse[A]{1}{F} LIBRO de la generación de Jesucristo,
hijo de David, hijo de Abraham. \fromFile \writeVerse[A]{1}{L}
\writeVerse[A]{2}{F} \textbf{2}~Abraham engendró á Isaac: é Isaac
engendró á Jacob: y Jacob engendró á Judas y á sus
hermanos:\writeVerse[A]{2}{L} \writeVerse[A]{3}{F} \textbf{3}~Y Judas
engendró de Thamar á Phares y á Zara: y Phares engendró á Esrom: y
Esrom engendró á Aram:\writeVerse[A]{3}{L}
\end{document}
```

The `\fromFile` macro reads one line of the input file at each call.

If I run the file with `-shell-escape`, the `\write18` istruction takes care of the name switching for the next run. You can do it with your script, of course.

Comment: Thanks but the `\fromFile` is really a replacement for writing out `\writeVerse{A}{1}{F}` etc. each time since due to other factors beyond the scope of the MWE the parameters will change for `\writeVerse`. So in reality you would not see `\writeVerse{A}{1}{F}` in there at all except in the aux files. This script gets called by an external OS script and might have to be run even up to a 1000 times before the layout would be satisfactory. But that's handled by the external script. This `TeX` file just need to be able to read an executable command from the first aux file and write to the second.

Comment: @McGafter Sorry, but I don't get it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I've given a small clarification in the OP for what it's worth. The main issue at present is reading a command from an aux file and executing it on the same run.

Comment: @McGafter You can't do that: if the file is open for writing, you can't (reliably) read from it.

Comment: I understand, but I want to read from the first file then write to a second file on the same run.

Comment: Could the problem of it not executing be related to the fact that according to the TeXbook p. 217 it reads it into a control sequence "and the control sequence is defined to be a parameterless macro..."? Whatever that might entail.